# NEO4J issues with gds.enterprise.license.file

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to start my neo4j server but I ran into this issue below; yes my gds license is good and  I made sure to "chown" the file so neo4j is the owner.

```
neo4j.service - Neo4j Graph Database
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-10-11 13:41:14 UTC; 6s ago
   Duration: 1.666s
    Process: 29539 ExecStart=/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j console (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 29539 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 3.944s

Oct 11 13:41:14 ip-172-31-2-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal neo4j[29539]: Validating Neo4j configuration: /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf
Oct 11 13:41:14 ip-172-31-2-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal neo4j[29539]: 1 issue found.
Oct 11 13:41:14 ip-172-31-2-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal neo4j[29539]: Error: Unrecognized setting. No declared setting with name: gds.enterprise.license_file. Cleanup the conf>
Oct 11 13:41:14 ip-172-31-2-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal neo4j[29539]: Skipping Log4j validation due to previous issues.
Oct 11 13:41:14 ip-172-31-2-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal neo4j[29539]: Configuration file validation failed.
Oct 11 13:41:14 ip-172-31-2-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal neo4j[29539]: Configuration contains errors. This validation can be performed again using 'neo4j-admin server validate->
Oct 11 13:41:14 ip-172-31-2-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal neo4j[29539]: Run with '--verbose' for a more detailed error message.
Oct 11 13:41:14 ip-172-31-2-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 11 13:41:14 ip-172-31-2-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 11 13:41:14 ip-172-31-2-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Consumed 3.944s CPU time.
```

I double checked my file in the neo4j.conf and it looks good to me:

[image]

Comment: Is `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` the location of your `neo4j.conf` file? If so, are there syntax errors anywhere in that file?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the GDS plugin installed?
Without the jar in the plugins folder Neo4j would throw this exception

Comment: Yep, the neo4j-graph-data-science-2.3.5.jar file is under the plugins directory

neo4j is the owner of the file as well

Comment: Okay, did you check if GDS 2.3.5 is compatible with your Neo4j version? (https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/installation/supported-neo4j-versions/)